# How to exit from parent calling function from child called function without throwing error

Tags: javascript, function

```
const funB = (param1) => {

  if(param1 === "test") {
    return "I am in testing mode"; // exit from this function
  }

  const value = "I am running the production flow";

  // Do other stuff

}

//////////refactor funB for usabilty purpose ////////////

const funA = (parm1)=> {

  if(param1 === "test") {
    return "I am in testing mode";
  }

  return "I am running the production flow";
}


const funB = (param1) => {

  // Call funA
  const value = funA();

  // Do other stuff

}
```

Problem: After refactoring, flow keeps executing because call for `funA()` is not breaking the `funB()` execution flow when `param1==="test"`

Q: How to solve this in refactor code?

Comment: You'll have to test `value === "test"` in `funB()` and if true, `return`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you've not set any default value for `function funA` parameter > `parm1` and also not passing any value to  `funA` in the time of invoking it inside `function funB` :
`const value = funA();`

You can call funA() with the necessary argument and do the necessary checking inside funB:

```
const funA = (parm1)=> {
  if(param1 === "test") {
    return "I am in testing mode";
  }
  return "I am running the production flow";
}

const funB = (param1) => {
  const reValue = funA(param1);
  if(reValue == "I am in testing mode") {
      return;
  }
  // Do other stuff
}
```